# Excel hiding columns based on certain crtieria

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

What if i have a cell that is a drop down list and based on the choice of this list ex contains the word "Marketing", hide some columns?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way, using VBA, is to:
Assign a named range to the cell that holds your Drop Down List box.
Check the Named Range value using Instr(). 
If true, hide a column.

```
  If InStr(ActiveSheet.Range("DDLB").Value, "Marketing") Then
    Columns("D:D").Hidden = True
  End If
```